# Coldfusion FarCry CMS error on start up after server reboot

Tags: content-management-system, coldfusion-8

We're using Farcry CMS which runs on top of ColdFusion. Site was running fine but we are getting this error message after a web server reboot.

"Failed to initialise core type: dmHTML.cfc"

"Parameter 1 of function IsDefined, which is now application.stcoapi.dmHTML.stWebskins.Copy of displayPageCalculatorSelector.displayname, must be a syntactically valid variable name."

Really not sure where to start, could anyone suggest a strategy for troubleshooting this type of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a file called "Copy of displayPageCalculatorSelector.cfm" in your dmHTML webskin folder.

Remove this file is the best option.

Or rename it and remove the spaces, e.g. "Copy_of_displayPageCalculatorSelector.cfm"